# Creating MYSQL table with foreign key ERROR

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `u914452720_yzawa`.`aucs_manufacturer_files` 
( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ('manufacturer_id') REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

got error:
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `u914452720_yzawa`.`aucs_manufacturer_files` 
( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ('manufacturer_id') REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE=INNODB
MySQL atsakymas: Dokumentacija
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''manufacturer_id') REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCA' at line 3

EXPORTED TABLE FROM WHICH I WANT TO GET MANUFACTURER_ID:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Generation Time: 2019 m. Grd 16 d. 11:37
-- Server version: 10.2.27-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.2.23

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `u914452720_yzawa`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Sukurta duomenų struktūra lentelei `aucs_manufacturer`
--

CREATE TABLE `aucs_manufacturer` (
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instruction` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catalog` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sketch` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `aucs_manufacturer`
--
ALTER TABLE `aucs_manufacturer`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`manufacturer_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `aucs_manufacturer`
--
ALTER TABLE `aucs_manufacturer`
  MODIFY `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: not 100% you need the quotes around the key name

Comment: Kindly remove 'manufacturer_id' single quotes.

Comment: I think you should use the backticks instead of quotes

Comment: @Jhecht still the error remains, tried without quotes :(

Comment: what is the exact key type of `aucs_manufacturer.manufacturer_id` ?

Comment: type is : int(11) Autoincrement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the single quotes might not be necessary and both the referenced table and the new table that is being created have to be on the same Engine (MyISAM in this case).

```
CREATE TABLE `aucs_manufacturer_files` 
( `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: tried adding PRIMARY KEY (id) but got error: #1005 - Can't create table `u914452720_yzawa`.`aucs_manufacturer_files` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Detalės…)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `aucs_manufacturer_files` 
( `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE=INNODB;

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table `u914452720_yzawa`.`aucs_manufacturer_files` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Detalės…)

Comment: The error you received is very cryptic. The problem might be that the foreign key column and the referencing column are not of the same type or length. Please check the datatypes of both the columns should be same

Comment: manufacturer_id primary int(11)AUTO_INCREMENT 
other keys are just varchars

Comment: Execute SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; This will enlighten us on what are we doing wrong.

Comment: CREATE TABLE aucs_manufacturer_files ( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , manufacturer_id INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS' at line 1

Comment: We just need to execute "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS", after executing CREATE TABLE aucs_manufacturer_files ( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , manufacturer_id INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;

Comment: It gives you verbose error details. I suspect index missing on the primary key column aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id)

Comment: @Emilis I found the issue. I have updated the query. Your referenced table is in the Engine MyISAM and you are trying to create the new table in INNODB. Both the tables have to be on the same engine. Change the engine name and add charset for the query to work. The above edited query is working

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a lot about the other table that you are trying to reference, it's hard for us to guess certain information. I put together [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ef132/1) to demonstrate a working solution.

```
create table am (
  id int unique not null auto_increment
)
ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE amf
( `id` INT unique NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES am(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE=INNODB;

insert into am(id) values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);
insert into amf(id, manufacturer_id) VALUES (null, 1),(null, 2),(null, 3),(null, 2),(null, 1),(null, 4),(null, 6);
delete from am where id = 6;
```

If you run the `SELECT * from amf` you will see that there are no values with the manufacturer_id as 6, meaning that the cascade worked correctly.

Comment: I think you are right, my manufacturer table is full of data. Your example works, but i don't know how to create new table with foreign key on existing table with 250 rows of data.

Comment: are you saying that you are _adding_ a foreign key onto a table that already exists?

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem. i can't imagine a scenario where you're creating a foreign key constraint on a table that doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope this would work:

```
  CREATE TABLE `u914452720_yzawa`.`aucs_manufacturer_files` 
    ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `manufacturer_id` INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
    ENGINE=INNODB
```

Comment: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: id is the primary key here

Comment: @SKYz no, it isn't a key at all, but should be :)

Answer (score 0):

After you fixed the single quotes that should have been backticks or removed altogether, you have:

```
CREATE TABLE `u914452720_yzawa`.`aucs_manufacturer_files` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ('manufacturer_id') REFERENCES aucs_manufacturer(manufacturer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

And you are getting this error:

```
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

This has nothing to do with the foreign key; it results from specifying auto increment for a column that is not a key.  Presumably you meant to say:

```
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

(If you end up with yet another error after fixing this, please make sure to edit your question with the new create statement, error message, and output from `show create table aucs_manufacturer`.)